# How to update an element in vector in atom state

Tags: clojurescript

I'm trying to create kind of todo list with ClojureScript and reagent framework. I defined app state as atom:

```
(def app-state
  (r/atom
   {:count 3
    :todolist
    [{:id 0 :text "Start learning mindcontrol" :finished true}
     {:id 1 :text "Read a book 'Debugging JS in IE11 without pain'" :finished false}
     {:id 2 :text "Become invisible for a while" :finished false}]}))
```

Have a function to update todo list:

```
(defn update-todolist [f & args]
  (apply swap! app-state update-in [:todolist] f args))
```

And function toggle todo:

```
(defn toggle-todo [todo]
  (update-todolist update-in [2] assoc :finished true))
```

Here I'm updating vector element directly by its index right now.

I'm rendering every item with this function:

```
(defn item [todo]
  ^{:key (:id todo)}
  [:div
   [:span {:class "item-text"} (:text todo)]
   [:i {:class (str "ti-check " (if (:finished todo) "checked" "unchecked"))
        :on-click #(toggle-todo (assoc todo :finished true))}]])
```

Here I'm passing updated todo but it's not correct to pass always true. Probably it would be enough to pass its index and it will solve my problem, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @AlanThompson how do I toggle finished property in particular element in vector. I have in my implementation to pass an index in toggle-todo, but I don’t know how to get it where function is invoked. Maybe there is totally different way to achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(def app-state
  (r/atom
   {:count 3
    :todolist
    [{:id 0 :text "Start learning mindcontrol" :finished true}
     {:id 1 :text "Read a book 'Debugging JS in IE11 without pain'" :finished false}
     {:id 2 :text "Become invisible for a while" :finished false}]}))


(defn update-todolist [f & args]
  (apply swap! app-state update-in [:todolist] f args))


(defn toggle-todo [todo]
  (swap! app-state update-in [:todolist (:id todo) :finished] not))


(defn item [todo]
  ^{:key (:id todo)}
  [:div
   [:span {:class "item-text"} (:text todo)]
   [:i {:class (str "ti-check " (if (:finished todo) "checked" "unchecked"))
        :on-click #(toggle-todo todo)}]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that just works. I need a better understanding of how update-in works.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the value of the `:finished` key, just use `not`:

```
(swap! app-state update-in [:todolist 2 :finished] not) => 

    {:count 3,
     :todolist
       [{:id 0, :text "Start learning mindcontrol", 
                :finished true}
        {:id 1, :text "Read a book 'Debugging JS in IE11 without pain'",
                :finished false}
        {:id 2, :text "Become invisible for a while", 
                :finished true}]}
```

However, this does not tell you how the index `2` corresponds with the map that has `:id 2` inside it.